# How to correctly inherit from a base class whose destructor is not virtual?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-destructor

I want to inherit from class A, but A's destructor is not virtual and I cannot modify A's definition. How to avoid the following case?

```
struct A
{
    A()
        : a(new char[8])
    {}

    ~A()
    {
        delete[] a;
    }

    char* a;
}

struct B : A
{
    B()
        : A(), b(new char[8])
    {}

    ~B()
    {
        delete[] b;
    }

    char* b;
};

int main()
{
    A* p_a = new B;
    delete p_a; // How to avoid such a dangerous deletion?
}
```

Comment: You are not following the rule of three. Please read about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the base class doesn't have a virtual destructor and you can't modify the class definition, you're pretty much out of luck.  As a general rule of thumb, you probably shouldn't use public inheritance with a base class that doesn't have a virtual destructor.

Maybe you can try using composition instead of inheritance?  Place an instance of `A` in `B`, and provide public member functions that wrap calls to member functions of `A`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `struct B : private A` so that `A` is an inaccessible base of `B`.

Comment: But he has : `A* p_a = new B;`

Comment: If so, the caller cannot use A's public members; that's not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the `A` a data member instead of a base class.

---

By the way, the classes violate the rule of three, which is an invitation to disaster. What if an instance is copied. Better use standard library containers instead of explicit `new` and `delete`.

Comment: @YuanWen: "Data member" is pretty fundamental. You're asking for sample code of declaring a variable. You need a textbook. The SO C++ [book list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) can help.